# Implicitly unwrapped multiplication and division

Tags: swift

I've isolated the following code in a playground. In the playground, I get the noted compile time errors:

```
class MyClass {
    var weight: Double!

    func toOunces() {
        weight *= 0.035274          // 'Double!' is not identical to 'UInt8'
        weight = weight * 0.035274  // works
    }

    func toGrams() {        
        weight /= 0.035274          // 'Double!' is not identical to 'Float'
        weight = weight / 0.035274  // works
    }
}
```

I was following an example online using NSCoder, where `decodeDoubleForKey() as Double?` was being used, hence the implicitly unwrapped optional `var weight: Double!`.

I'm debating how correct this is to even do, and I fixed it in my code.

**My question is, why these compile time errors?** Why does multiplication compare to UInt8 and division compares to Float? Is there something I've been missing for years regarding *= and /= ?

I'm still learning this, so I'm probably missing some basic property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the *= operator work by explicitly unwrapping the optional first like so:

```
func toOunces() {
    weight! *= 0.035274
}
```

You can see why this is looking at how *= is defined.

```
func *=(inout lhs: Double, rhs: Double)
```

An implicitly unwrapped optional can't be passed as an inout parameter because it is a wrapper around a Double (or nil.)

Non inout arguments can be unwrapped automatically because the function just needs the value which can be extracted from the optional automatically rather than a reference to the actual value. That's why the * operator works for `Double!` which is defined as such.

```
func *(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
```

Adding the ! after weight in your code changes it from passing a reference to the optional to passing a reference to the Double encased in the Optional. If *= had a normal function syntax and we remove some sugar it might look like this:

```
func multiplyAssign (inout lhs: Double, rhs: Double){
    lhs = rhs * lhs
}
var weight: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Double> = 0.0
multiplyAssign(&weight, 10.0) //trying to pass reference to an ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Double> (error)
multiplyAssign(&(weight!), 10.0) //passing a reference to a Double
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I have the answer, but you're not going to like it.

`*=` is defined as such

```
func *=(inout lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8)

func *=(inout lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8)

func *=(inout lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16)

func *=(inout lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16)

func *=(inout lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32)

func *=(inout lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32)

func *=(inout lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64)

func *=(inout lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64)

func *=(inout lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt)

func *=(inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int)

func *=(inout lhs: Float, rhs: Float)

func *=(inout lhs: Double, rhs: Double)


/// multiply `lhs` and `rhs` and store the result in `lhs`, trapping in
/// case of arithmetic overflow (except in -Ounchecked builds).
func *=<T : _IntegerArithmeticType>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T)

func *=(inout lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80)
```

`/=` is defined as

```
func /=(inout lhs: Float, rhs: Float)

func /=(inout lhs: Double, rhs: Double)

func /=(inout lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80)


/// divide `lhs` and `rhs` and store the result in `lhs`, trapping in
/// case of arithmetic overflow (except in -Ounchecked builds).
func /=<T : _IntegerArithmeticType>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T)
```

The `/` and `*` operators don't have an `inout` specifier on their first parameter, were as `/=` and `*=` do. The other thing I notice is `UInt8` is the first `*=` operator and `Float` is the first `/=` operator.

---

Putting this all together, `Double!` can be coerced into `Double`, but cannot be coerced into `inout Double`. In both cases the error message is picking the first version of the operator method to report in the error.